# How to Navigate from Jtable rows

Tags: swing

I am currently developing swing application. I have a feature to implement which i do not know how to do it.

How to open/load another page onclick of Jtable rows ?

Am thinking to clear entire frame and reload with new one . Is that Good Idea ?

Jtable is in tab1.
Now I want to open Tab3 and populate values when i click on jtable row which is on tab1

Comment: You can provide a button to proceed to next tab. Get the selected row's data and then proceed to populate the values with these selected row's values.

Comment: Thank you. on click of button 1 page A will open, on click of button 2 page B will open. page B has tab A ,Tab B and Tab c. I have Jtable in Page A. Question is show to move from Page A to Tab 3 of Page B. Thank you

Comment: It was jumbled a bit. Let me clear my doubts. 
You want to display data of table from `pageA` on the `TabC` of `pageB` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a little research. I'll suggest you to add a `MouseClick` event to your JTable. On clicking any of the element of table, you can fetch the data of the position from table you clicked by writing code like-

`String data = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),jTable1.getSelectedColumn()).toString();`

Now data is the data that you want to display from pageA. You can now easily set this `data` to tab3 of pageB.